# match string/string of array using loop and if condition - php

Tags: php, arrays, regex, string

This is a common simple question that bothers me. I have an array stored in a variable and I want to search and match the string array value($myarray) from a string that is stored in a variable($match). How can I match the values using loop and count it if how many matches are there? Should I use for loop or while loop or for each?
This is my sample data.

```
$myArray = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
$count = count($myArray);
$match = 'six';
$match2 = array('car', 'dog');

for ($myArray=0; $myArray < $count; $myArray++) { 
    if($myArray == $match){
        echo 'do something';
    }else{
        echo 'do something';
    }
}
```

Also is it possible to match the value of one array to another array? For example, I want to search all the values of $myArray and match it to the values of $match2 and return all matches(like: 2 matches out of 10 items)

I don't have enough knowledge in loops or handling arrays.
Thank you for help.

Comment: I prefer to use `foreach` because it's simpler and more obvious what you're doing. But to each his own, you can use whatever you like.

Comment: Thanks for giving me additional idea. Now I have something in mind to follow. Can you give me a sample code using for each loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the function you're looking for is `array_intersect()`. You give this 2 arrays, and it returns an array containing the elements that they have in common. You can then use `count()` to get the number.

```
$matches = count(array_intersect($myArray, $match2));
```

Comment: PHP has several handy built-in array functions: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php

Comment: Wow! nice it counts all matches. how about if I want to echo all the matched values?

Comment: Put the result of `array_intersect` in a variable and loop over it.

Comment: I'm not good in looping but I will try it. Can you give me example?

Comment: There's nothing to it. `foreach ($array as $element) {echo $element;}`

Comment: You can't be a competent programmer if you're not good at looping. It's one of the most basic concepts.

Comment: Thanks! if array_intersect works on both array, is it possible to use it to a non array? or is it possible to use it like ($matches = count(array_intersect($myArray, $match));) $match is not an array and it contains only a string.

Comment: If you just want to search for a single element, use `in_array()`.

Comment: If you want to know what is possible, why don't you read the documentation?

Comment: Do you have a PHP textbook? It should have a chapter on arrays that explains all the things you can do with them. I don't want to spend all day answering every followup question you have. You need to learn how to do research on your own, not have everything spoon-fed to you.

Comment: Thanks again for helping me out. I really appreciate it and I really learn from your answers. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need a variable, not your array variable, to see the current index in your cycle, we'll name this one `index`, then you compare the string in that position with the string you want yo match.

```
$myArray = array('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five');
$count = count($myArray);
$match = 'six';
$match2 = array('car', 'dog');
$numberMatches = 0;

for ($index=0; $index < $count; $index++) { 
    if($myArray[index] == $match){
        echo "It matches" ;
        $numberMatches++;
    }else{
        echo "It doesn' t match";
    }
}
```